# Adding an array of UIButtons to navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem results in NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am trying to add an array of 2 buttons to the right of a navigation bar, but I get a exception when I run the code.

**'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton isSystemItem]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**

My code is pretty simple really:

```
   UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,45)];
   label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
   label.text = @"Test 2 Buttons";

   UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   button1.frame = CGRectMake(00.0f, 0.0f, 32.0f, 32.0f);

   UIButton *button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   button2.frame = CGRectMake(00.0f, 0.0f, 32.0f, 32.0f);

   NSArray *rightBarButtons = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:button2, button1, nil];


   UINavigationItem* navItem = self.navigationItem;
   navItem.titleView = label;
   navItem.rightBarButtonItems = rightBarButtons;
   [rightBarButtons release];
   [label release];
```

I am running it on the iPhone 5.0 simulator.
Any idea??
Thanks in advance.
Al

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can't directly add `UIButtons`.  You need to wrap them as `UIBarButtonItems` first - there is no compiler warning since you are only passing an array.

Create the bar button items using `initWithCustomView:`, passing in your button as the custom view. Or, depending on what is in your buttons, create bar button items directly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have noticed that. So simple :-)

Comment: Replace `UIButton` with `UIBarButtonItem` and it works. You don't need to create it with `initWithCustomView`.  Make sure you assign the Array of UIBarButtonItems to `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItemS` with the **S** on the end

Comment: @proca2.0 yes, hence **"Or, depending on what is in your buttons, create bar button items directly."**

Answer (score 10):

The trick here is to use UIBarButtonItem objects instead of UIButton objects.  UIBarButtonItems can be created from UIButtons like so:

```
UIBarButtonItem *myItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:uibuttonObject];
```

However, using UIButtons in a navigation bar is generally a bad idea, when UIBarButtonItems are meant to look pretty there.  Consider visiting the [UIBarButtonItem Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

You are meant to give it an array of [UIBarButtonItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIBarButtonItem) objects not UIButton objects. Note that UIBarButtonItem inherits neither from UIButton nor UIView.