# Adding an array of UIBarButtonItem resulting in an Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI isSystemItem]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa5bbd726f0'

I have followed his [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279803/adding-an-array-of-uibuttons-to-navigationitem-rightbarbuttonitem-results-in-nsi), and apparently I am doing no flaw. What I am doing is - adding two buttons(bar buttons) on the right side of my navigation bar.

```
     UIBarButtonItem *notificationButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Notification.png"]
                                                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(notificationAction)];
        UIBarButtonItem *searchButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search"]
                                                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(searchAction)];
        NSArray *arrNavigationButtons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:notificationButtonItem,searchButtonItem, nil];
// warning here - Incompatible pointer type.
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = arrNavigationButtons;
```

Comment: The 2 answers you've gotten have told you what the problem is and how to fix it. You should have gotten a compiler warning. Warnings are your friend.  Pay close attention to them.

Comment: @DuncanC . That was a silly mistake. I'll be better next time. thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the last line to `rightBarButtonItems`. Notice the s at the end.

Answer (score 1):

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem is a single ButtonItem and you are passing an NSArray to it which is invalid call. To pass NavigationBarButtons you need to call right function. I think you will get warning for incompatible pointer type if you call that. Just change your code to:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = arrNavigationButtons;
```